# MSFT Teams does not render adaptive card with DATE function

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have an adaptive card with some text & input fields. The card would show up fine in Bot emulator but it would not render in teams. I have analyzed the issue to be related to **DATE** function. Consider the following simple card

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "{{DATE(2018-03-26T08:00:00Z)}}"
        }
    ]
}
```

The above card would render fine in https://www.adaptivecards.io/designer or Bot emulator but it would not render in MSFT Teams. I even tried it in **App studio (Card Editor)** in MSFT Teams. App studio (Card Editor) would show proper preview but when I click on **Send me this card**, it comes blank

[image: App studio (Card Editor)]

[image: App studio blank Card]

This was working fine in Teams some time back (maybe a week(s) ago) I would really appreciate it if you guys can help me fix or find a workaround to this issue. Thanks...

Comment: We could not reproduce the issue on our side. Could you please try signout/signin

Comment: strange, restarting solved the issue. Thanks...

Comment: most probably the issues is with the context as it will have the historical values.

Answer (score 0):

Funny & strange, It cost me a day but restarting Teams solved the issue. Thanks...